# Fatal error: Uncaught exception- GuzzleHttp

Tags: php

Im making this thread because i doesn't find any proper solution that helpful for me and anybody can tell me that what i'm making mistake in my codes..
I have testing coinbase API v2 with my php website and its capable to run all these codes
like

```
$client = Client::create($configuration);
```

`$auth = $client->getCurrentAuthorization();`

```
$user = $client->getCurrentUser();
```

But when i try to run

```
$address = $client->getAccountAddress($account,$accountId);
```

Its throw the following error , i got the screenshot here..
[GuzzleHttp -exception error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNR97.png)

and finally here is my sample code im working with.

```
require_once'coinbase/vendor/autoload.php';
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Coinbase;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\Param;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Exception;
use \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
$apiKey ="xxxxxxx";
$apiSecret ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
$auth = $client->getCurrentAuthorization();
$user = $client->getCurrentUser();
$user = $client->getUser("xxxxxxxxx");
$user = $client->decodeLastResponse();
$accounts = $client->getAccounts(['name'=>'BTC Wallet']);
$accounts = $client->decodeLastResponse();
echo"USERS<br>";
var_dump($user);
echo"ACCOUNTS<br>";
var_dump($accounts);
$account = new Account([
    'name' => 'SoddisFare'
]);
$address = new Address([
    'name' => 'New Address19'
]);
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddresses($account);
//$account =$client->decodeLastResponse();
//$account =$client->decodeLastResponse();
echo "ACCOUNT ADDRESS<br>";
$address = $client->getAccountAddress($account,"xxxxxxxx");
var_dump($account);
```

I think the problem is actually with the argument passed to  `$client->getAccountAddress($account,"xxxxxxxx");`but i did  exactly same as what documentation says  ..
Please really need help on this ...

thanks

Comment: A `404 - Not found` error means that `ehy, I can't find this resource`

Comment: hi.. i noticed it but what i can do to solve it ...

Comment: is that possible to catch the error , but i confused it will fix the problem and can return the result..